# AlarmManager Does not work when Activity in background

Tags: android, background, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my App, I'm using AlarmManager for transmitting keep-alive every day once a day.
I'm using the following code for starting athe AlaramManager

```
        Calendar calendar = DateUtils
            .getNextKeepAliveTime(keepAliveHours, keepAliveMinutes);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0); //  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    Log.d(TAG, "cal: " + calendar.toString());
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long diff = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(diff < 0) diff = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, diff, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

When activity goes background, the receiver, AlarmReceiver, does not get any event. But it working successfully when activity in foreground.
Ther receiver declaration in my manifest is -

```
<receiver android:name="MainActivity$AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
```

The manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.ui.Settings" >
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="MainActivity$ChargingOnReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.services.MailSenderService" />
    <service android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.services.SmsSender" />

    <activity android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.ui.YDSiteView" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.ui.BatteryAlertDialog"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.yachtdroid.ba.ui.ActivityLog"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog" />
    <receiver android:name="MainActivity$AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
        <!-- intent-filter>
            <action android:name="alarm_action"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver -->
</application>
```

The receiver code is

```
    public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, intent.getExtras().toString());
        if (!inForeground) {
            Log.d(TAG, "*** Move app to front!");
            Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
            it.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    MainActivity.class.getName()));
            it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
        }           
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "alarm message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MainActivity.instance.sendKeepALive();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How it can be solved?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: Are you sure that the receiver isn't getting called? How do you know? Post the code from your `AlarmReceiver` class and your manifest.

Comment: Hi David, I'm using debugger for this purpose, I also insert a Toast in the receiver and Log to a log file.
I'm using the following command in my manifest -
<receiver android:name="MainActivity$AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" />

Comment: Please post the code for your `onReceive()`. Not in a comment, just edit your question. You can also put the manifest entry in there as well.

Comment: First thing I would do is to remove the `launchMode="singleInstance"` from your activity declaration. See if that helps. You probably don't want that anyway.

Comment: Also, the documentation for "setInexactRepeating()` says that the trigger time is inexact. It can vary up to an entire interval! Since your interval is a whole day, it is possible that the trigger doesn't happen until the next day! If you need more exact timing, you cannot use `setInexactRepeating()`

Comment: I have tested this with 5 minutes interval and facing the same results.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this. Can you please add some logging in your `onReceive()` method as the first line of code that is executed and see if this method is being called? I see no reason why the method should be called if the app is in the foreground, but not if it is in the background. Also, watch your logcat and don't filter it because you might miss something important/relevant.

Comment: Hi David, I'm happy to inform you that my app is working correctly. Thanks for your help. Eyal.

Comment: Can you please explain how you fixed this? Or what you discovered that was broken? It will certainly help others who read your question.

Comment: I'm using Service in PendingIntent for handling the AlarmManager event.

Comment: Hi eyal, since you fixed this problem can you please put your updated code in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have this code anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the code for the broadcast receiver from the Activity ,make another java file and put it there and also modify your manifest as per that

```
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

instead of

```
<receiver android:name="MainActivity$AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
```