# AlarmManager doesn't work in sleep mode when launchMode is on

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, sleep, wakeup

I have a activity A, and I have to call activity A again by AlarmManager. After that phone goes to sleep and wakes up by alarmmanager 30 mins later. The code is as follow:

```
public void wakeup(){
    Intent i = new Intent(mcontext, activity_form.class);
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(mcontext, 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    AlarmManager am =  (AlarmManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);    
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
} 
public void sleep(){
    pm = (PowerManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    pm.goToSleep(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());   
}
```

However, I don't want to create activity A again, so I hope my activity is singleton, and I add this in my Manifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
or
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

30 mins later, I see wakeup call in logcat, but phone doesn't wake up. If I delete android:launchMode, it's okay and wake up successfully. However, I will create activity A again.
A -> set alarm -> sleep -> wake up -> A' But my hope is A -> set alarm -> sleep -> wake up -> A
I have no idea about that, thank you a lot.

Comment: What is your activity_form.class shows service or broadcast receiver?

Comment: See this link, there is answer of your questions, need to check it carefully : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080531/alarmmanager-does-not-work-when-activity-in-background

Comment: It is just a show service, not a receiver. If I remove launchmode = "singleInstance", alarm can work successfully. Duplicate activity will happen. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) if you want to wake up your phone with your activity. You can find implemention [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

It requires `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: Thanks, but I have already added it in my xml. Phone can wake up successfully with launchMode is standard. However, it can't work in singleTask or another launchmode.